# Number system representation

Tags: matrices, number-systems

Can anyone help with the highlighted parts of the question below?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Part (b)(i)**
Note the floating point representation of the fraction: $\frac{5}{9} = .555555$.

The calculations step-by-step:
$$
\begin{align}
A(B^T+C^T) &= A \begin{bmatrix}0.2 \\.11\cdot 10^1 \end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}0.13 \\.221'111 \end{bmatrix}
\\
AB^T &= \begin{bmatrix}0.11 \\.155'555 \end{bmatrix}
\\
AC^T &= \begin{bmatrix}0.2 \cdot 10^{-1} \\.655'555 \cdot 10^{-1} \end{bmatrix}
\\
\implies AB^T + AC^T &= \begin{bmatrix}0.13 \\.221'110 \end{bmatrix}\,.
\end{align}
$$
The floating-point operations are explained in depth at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic).

**Part (b)(ii)**
Sum positive and negative numbers separately and finally add them. Furthermore, successively add from smallest absolute value to largest.